# How to completely redefine `res.render` method in salsjs?

Tags: sails.js

I would like to completely redefine **res.render** method in **sailsjs** app: 
my template engine is not compatible with consolidate.

I decided to use **hook** for it, but can't understand, how I can to write my own realization of **res.render**.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the same as here [lib/hooks/views/index.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/v0.11.0/lib/hooks/views/index.js#L53-L60) (in your sails hook)

```js
sails.on('router:before', function() {
    sails.router.bind('/*', function(req, res, next) {
        // here you can reimplement the res.render method, of example:
         res.render = function render(data) {
             // For access `req` data in your template engine,
             // many useful info stored here like:
             // req.options.controller – current `controller`
             // req.options.action – current `action`
             data.req = req;

             var html = yourTemplateEngineRender(data);

             res.set({
                 'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                 'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(html, 'utf8')
             });

             res.send(html);
         } 
    }, 'all');
});
```

See my hook which enables [bem](https://en.bem.info) rendering for sails: [sails-hook-bem-render](https://github.com/alexbaumgertner/sails-hook-bem-render/blob/v0.0.4/index.js#L25-L52)